# Angular 6 bug in Chrome, function($event) randomly throws error "can't read property "value" of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, debugging, angular6

It seems that the buttons are iterated correctly by ngFor and if I inspect them they have the right attributes, however, when I click on them the function in the controller claims the parameter is 'undefined' every now and then, I guess 50-50 most of the time, quite random.

This is the error I get: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at (the line where the attribute is passed as a parameter in the controller)

Everything worked fine when all the logic was within its controller. But I decided to refactor it and use a service + interceptors. For now, I've included the headers and params in the service.

The thing is, everything works fine in Firefox with no errors, Chrome seems to be the only one experiencing this bug. And if I keep clicking on it, it will keep throwing errors for a while until it just works. Here's a screen recording: https://streamable.com/5f7og

Note: If I just wait without clicking again and again -- nothing happens. Looking in the network tab reveals that the http call simply isn't firing at all.

Code below:

Front end:

```html
<div *ngFor="let button of lvl0 | errorfix">
  <!-- Actual buttons reiterated with ngIF -->
  <button mat-raised-button color="accent" [attr.data-param1]=" button['md:0/413349530_Level 0 – Section'] | lvl0clean "
    class="lvl0button" (click)="reveallvl1($event)" (click)="stepper.reset()" (click)="resetAllSteps()">
    {{ button['md:0/413349530_Level 0 – Section'] | lvl0clean }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Service:

```js
initialisingDocs() {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();

  headers = headers.append(
    "Authorization",
    "Basic " + btoa("SOMETHINGSOMETHING")
  );
  headers = headers.append(
    "Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  );
  return this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL + "initialising", { headers });
}
```

Controller:

```js
constructor(private service: DocsService) {
  // Initialising the first set of buttons

  this.lvl0 = this.service.initialisingDocs().subscribe(data => {
    this.lvl0 = data;
    console.log(this.lvl0);
  });
}
```

For the next lvl of buttons:

```js
reveallvl1($event) {
  this.service
    .lvl1Docs($event.target.attributes["data-param1"].value) **// <<ERROR LINE>>**
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.lvl1 = data;
      console.log(data);

      this.step1Folder($event.target.attributes["data-param1"].value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround, instead of using the $event object to pass the attributes to the function, I just iterated them directly following the advice of someone from here in another thread:

[Angular 6 attribute binding bug, possible workarounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560936/angular-6-attribute-binding-bug-possible-workarounds)