# Angular 6 attribute binding bug, possible workarounds?

Tags: angular, debugging, attributes, ngfor

I have a series of button created by ngFor which all have custom attributes binded like this:

```
[attr.queryParam1]="button['something'] | clean"
(click)="next($event)"
```

Then in the controller:

```
this.service.lvl1Docs($event.target.attributes["queryParam1"].value).subscribe
```

But in chrome I'm getting very inconsistent behaviour, the source seems to reveal the attributes are there and are correct but if I click them I get this error in console and nothing happens:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at DocsBuilderComponent.push../src/app/docs-builder
/docs-builder.component.ts.DocsBuilderComponent.reveallvl1
```

Everything seems to work fine in firefox though and if I keep clicking in chrome it eventually works fine. I had no luck troubleshooting this all week and I can't seem to effectively reproduce from scratch.

My question is, is there a better/different way to bind these two so I can send that iterated attribute as a GET request param?

I should mention I need to use about 5 params for each button slightly later on and can't bind to something like 'value' or 'id', hence trying to use attribute binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ***ngFor** you have access to all the items that are being looped over. So why add attributes to a button if you just need the data that attribute may or may not contain.

Whatever array you are iterating over, add the query param fields to the objects within the array.

Heres an example

```
<button *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="next(item.queryParamsOrWhatever)">
  {{item.buttonName}}
</button>
```

Does this answer your question? Or is their some reason you need to add attributes to the button.

Comment: All I can say is lol, why haven't I thought of that. That seems to make so much sense and is so much simpler than my solution with bundling all attributes in the $event object and then passing that and reading that there.

Will refactor now using this logic and will get back here and reply, thanks a lot man! I literally dumped over 8 hours of fully-focused work into this issue.

Comment: @Pezzeter That did the trick! Such a better way of doing it. Everything seems to work fine and no more errors in Chrome!